# How to change timestamp to numeric format in hours in R

Tags: r

I currently have a column of time in HH:MM:SS format and need to convert it to a numeric hour value

`[1] "0:00:00"  "0:10:00"  "0:20:00"  "0:30:00"  "0:40:00"`  
`[6] "0:50:00"  "1:00:00"  "1:10:00"  "1:20:00"  "1:30:00"`  
`[11] "1:40:00"  "1:50:00"  "2:00:00"  "2:10:00"  "2:20:00"`

I was going to use the program `lubridate` but is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Please paste in your data using results of `dput(mydata column)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R: Convert hours:minutes:seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29067375/r-convert-hoursminutesseconds)

Comment: What do you mean with a numeric hour value? Do you mean that 0:00:00 becomes 0.0, 0:10:00 becomes 0.1, and 1:10:00 becomes 1.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```r
sapply(strsplit(vec, ":"), function(x) {
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  x[1] + x[2]/60 + x[3]/3600 })
#>  [1] 0.0000000 0.1666667 0.3333333 0.5000000 0.6666667 0.8333333 1.0000000
#>  [8] 1.1666667 1.3333333 1.5000000 1.6666667 1.8333333 2.0000000 2.1666667
#> [15] 2.3333333
```

---

**Data**

```r
vec <- c("0:00:00", "0:10:00", "0:20:00", "0:30:00", "0:40:00", "0:50:00", 
         "1:00:00", "1:10:00", "1:20:00", "1:30:00", "1:40:00", "1:50:00", 
         "2:00:00", "2:10:00", "2:20:00")

vec
#>  [1] "0:00:00" "0:10:00" "0:20:00" "0:30:00" "0:40:00" "0:50:00" "1:00:00" 
#>  [8] "1:10:00" "1:20:00" "1:30:00" "1:40:00" "1:50:00" "2:00:00" "2:10:00" 
#> [15] "2:20:00"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

An option with `lubridate` is

```
library(lubridate)
period_to_seconds(hms(vec))/3600
#[1] 0.0000000 0.1666667 0.3333333 0.5000000 0.6666667 0.8333333 1.0000000 1.1666667 1.3333333 1.5000000 1.6666667 1.8333333 2.0000000
#[14] 2.1666667 2.3333333
```

data

```
vec <- c("0:00:00", "0:10:00", "0:20:00", "0:30:00", "0:40:00", "0:50:00", 
     "1:00:00", "1:10:00", "1:20:00", "1:30:00", "1:40:00", "1:50:00", 
     "2:00:00", "2:10:00", "2:20:00")
```