# Calculate how long each row's time period overlaps with other rows

Tags: r

Each row records the start time and end time of a time period. To simply, we assume all are in the same day, so we don't need to bother other more difficult issues.

I need to calculate how long each row's time period overlaps with other rows. And the number of rows that have such overlaps. Suppose I have a data set. I want column D and column E.

There is no sample data. I just use this fake data set to make an example.

```
dat <- data.frame(id=1:4, 
                                    Start = c("02:50","02:55","03:15","03:25"),
                   End = c("03:10", "03:05", "03:20", "03:30"),
                   num_overlap = c(1,1,0,0),
                   time_overlap = c(10,10,0,0))

dat
```

Comment: That’s not data. That’s an image. We don’t do images here.

Comment: Because there is no data. I just make an image (Excel) to exemplify my point.

Comment: Post code that creates a dataset. And post also code that creates the expected answer. Otherwise you are demanding that we do that preparation for you. Most of us think that’s your job. The fact that you are quibbling after being advised about local expectation is not a good sign.

Comment: You don't need to be such mean to me. This is my first post. Can you tell me how to "Post code that creates a dataset."?

Comment: Read [ask],  [MCVE] and search for the question: “How  to make a great reproducible example in R”

Comment: And if you think I’m “mean” then you are welcome to flag this for moderation. I thought I was telling useful facts about the local expectations for questions. Sometimes the moderator will decide that my comments are too direct. Wishing that you will grow in your understanding.

Comment: That's okay. Thank you for pointing out my mistake. I create a data set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using the `foverlaps` method within the `data.table` package:

Packages:

```
library(data.table)
library(chron) # To convert the times provided into a `times` format
```

Your data:

```
dat <- data.frame(id=1:4, 
              Start = c("02:50","02:55","03:15","03:25"),
              End = c("03:10", "03:05", "03:20", "03:30"))
```

I assume your times represent hours and minutes, so need to add the seconds ":00" and format as a `times` object:

```
dat$Start = times(paste0(dat$Start, ":00"))
dat$End = times(paste0(dat$End,":00"))
```

We will use the `data.table` package so we coerce the data frame to a data.table object

```
setDT(dat)
```

Set the `Start` and `End` time columns as keys for merging and then call the `foverlaps` function

```
setkey(dat, "Start", "End")

# Merge onto itself to find overlaps
overlaps = foverlaps(dat, dat, type = "any")
```

(See more on `foverlaps` here at https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.2/topics/foverlaps)

`foverlaps` keeps cases where the match was with itself (id = i.id) so we remove them

```
overlaps = overlaps[id != i.id]
```

Next, compute the amount of overlap, for each overlap that occurred

```
overlaps[, time_overlap := pmin(i.End, End) - pmax(i.Start, Start)]
```

Convert to minutes per https://stackoverflow.com/a/29067748/3674399

```
overlaps[, time_overlap := 60 * 24 * as.numeric(time_overlap)]
```

Keep only id and time_overlap, and summarize by id

```
overlaps = overlaps[, list(id, time_overlap)]
overlaps = overlaps[, list(num_overlap = .N, time_overlap = sum(time_overlap)), by = "id"]
```

Finally, merge with original dataset now, and fill any missing values

```
result = merge(dat, overlaps, by = "id", all.x = T)
result[is.na(num_overlap), num_overlap := 0]
result[is.na(time_overlap), time_overlap := 0]
```

The result is as follows:

```
   id    Start      End num_overlap time_overlap
1:  1 02:50:00 03:10:00           1           10
2:  2 02:55:00 03:05:00           1           10
3:  3 03:15:00 03:20:00           0            0
4:  4 03:25:00 03:30:00           0            0
```

If you are new to the data.table syntax, please see for example, this intro here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html